# iOS application crashes when using [UIImageView startAnimating] method

Tags: objective-c, ipad, memory-management

in my nib file I have a UIImageView that I have linked to my variable `IBOutlet UIImageView* imgH6;`  I need to play several animations therefore I have decided to play them on imgH6. for example if I want to start animating a group of images I will do: `[self playAnimation1];`

```
-(void) playAnimation1{

   NSArray *imagesArrayDilema;

   imagesArrayDilema = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dilema1-02.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dilema1-03.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dilema1-04.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"dilema1-05.png"] 
                                 // .....
                                 // there are several images
                                 , nil];

   imgH6.animationImages = imagesArrayDilema;

   // I will then start the animation as:
   wait = ((double)[imgH6.animationImages count])/30;
   [imgH6 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
   imgH6.animationDuration = wait;
   [imgH6 startAnimating];
}



-(void) playAnimation2{

   NSArray *imagesArrayDilema;

   imagesArrayDilema = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"differentImage-01.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"differentImage-02.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"differentImage-03.png"], 
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"differentImage-04.png"], 
                                 // .....
                                 // there are several images
                                 , nil];

   imgH6.animationImages = imagesArrayDilema;

   // I will then start the animation as:
   wait = ((double)[imgH6.animationImages count])/30;
   [imgH6 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
   imgH6.animationDuration = wait;
   [imgH6 startAnimating];
}

 ///.....
 // ...
-(void) playAnimation8{ // etc...
```

so when I call `[self playAnimation1];` there is no problem. the animation animates fine. I may also call `[self playAnimation7];` and a different group of images animate. I am able to do this several times but eventually the application crashes! In order to fix this I have done the following:  I have a global BOOL variable called isAnimating and what that does is that every time there is an animation in place you will not be able to animate a different group of images until the animation is done. Before I used to have the method:

```
-(void) animateMain :(NSArray*) imagesArray{

       imgH6.animationImages = imagesArray;

       // I will then start the animation as:
       double wait = ((double)[imgH6.animationImages count])/30;
       [imgH6 setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
       imgH6.animationDuration = wait;
       [imgH6 startAnimating];


}
```

and the application still crashed after playing several times. I have noticed that it crashes when changing the animation several times. In other words if I alway splay the same animation it does not crash...

also I do not used the word alloc or init to instantiate the array so I don't think this has to do with releasing the array.

Comment: Can yo please give more details on that crash?

Comment: That is something stange too. On xcode I select to run the application on my iPad and when the application crashes there are no errors that show up on xcode. The application on my ipad just closses. I don't know if I accidentaly changed some of the debug settings on xcode. Everytime I try to debug xcode seems to be debuging something else... Some other times the error shows up on xcode but this error that I am trying to look fore never appears on xcode

Comment: Make sure your breakpoints are enabled. Add a the following symbolic breakpoints: objc_exception_throw, malloc_error_break, [NSException raise]. Take a look at: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH1-SW1.

Also, check your console for crash logs.

Comment: I know just the basics of xcode... I will be working on that. Thanks

Comment: Were you able to find what was the crash about?

Comment: Maybe it has to do with several things being animated at once? I think it does not have to do with memory leaking because I alloc very few objects in my code and I am sure they get released. There is more stuff going on the app but I have used that functionality on other slides thats why I am assuming that it has to when using the [UIImageView StartAnimating] method. Moreover, when I comment out those lines the app does not crash. So what I am thinking about trying tomorrow morning is to create a nib file with just the methods that I posted in here.

Comment: And regarding the breakpoint stuff that you mentioned I where not able to locate the breakpoint navigator. But I assumed that it is enabled because if I place a breakpoint on my .m file xcode will stop in it. Sometimes it stopes after the breakpoint I do not understand why!? . Lasty I threw some errors on purpose and xcode did stoped with a execude bad sigabit some exeption like that. So based on this I thought that I had enabled what you mentioned...